# Run a string having dictionary syntax with exec() in python

Tags: python, dictionary, automation, exec

```
txt_cmd = f"output_{oem_alias}_.rename(columns = {'code_tagic':'code_pred'},inplace=True)";exec(txt_cmd)
```

Trying to execute a ditionary as a string in exec,error i am getting is as shown in image below.

[image]

Comment: txt_cmd = f"output_{oem_alias}_.rename(columns = {'{'}'code_tagic':'code_pred'{'}'},inplace=True)";exec(txt_cmd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
txt_cmd = f"output_{oem_alias}_.rename(columns = {'{'}'code_tagic':'code_pred'{'}'},inplace=True)";exec(txt_cmd)
```

Just Try using `{'{'}` for `{` & {'}'} for `}` this especially used in dictionary.